# Showing PDF in PopUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using asp.net mvc and i want to show pdf in a jquery dialog or inside boostrap modal popup.

I tried ajax call but if controller action is returning File with `Return File(....)` then it is giving wrong output in popup.

If i use iframe then when i am specifying url inside iframe it is redirecting to Httpget controller action but i want it to redirect to httppost controller action(because i have to post form also).

Actually why i want to open pdf inside popup or iframe is because right now pdf is opening in the same window but i want it to open in new browser tab or inside popup or inside iframe so that visitor continue to use website without pressing browser back button.

I am stuck with this..Plz help..!!!!

Comment: to open a PDF, if the browser does not have any plugin like Chrome does, **it will never ever open the PDF**... you should simply send the stream back to the user so the `Save As`... dialog box pops up... for that, there's plenty of examples here in Stackoverflow as well on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use GET request with an iframe and this is the right way to do it. So if you create the PDF with a POST request you need to return some kind of file ID or the file name. And then in your iframe do get the file using the ID or file name.

1. POST request for creating the PDF which returns an `ID` or `filename`
2. GET request `/path/to/your/pdf_files/<filename>.pdf` in an iframe.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to display small files (this method is not recommended for big files) which come from a previous POST request without saving them anywhere then use a data URL:

```
  <iframe type="application/pdf"
        width="95%"
        height="95%"
        src="data:application/pdf;base64,<base64_encoded_pdf_file_string_here>">
  </iframe>
```

Just replace **`<base64_encoded_pdf_file_string_here>`** with the actual base64 string representation of the file.

In order to get the base64 string of a stream make use of the [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

A bit dirty way, but you can create some kind of a "proxy" page, where you will direct your IFRame first, and where you will have a form (or you can even build it without the proxy page by using javascript only - it can be invisible, the form itself). Then you pass your data to this form inside the iframe by the help of javascript and issue the submit action on that form. By that way you will issue a POST request (if you configure your form correctly of course).

UPD: a simple example:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var form = iframe.contentDocument.createElement("form");
form.action="http://example.com/myuri";
form.method="post";
iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(form);
var data = iframe.contentDocument.createElement("input"); // You can create more of these "data" variables if you wish to pass more data to the server
data.type="hidden";
data.name="data_field";
data.value="somevalue";
form.appendChild(data);
form.submit(); // This actually executes the form and passing all data as POST data to the server
```